# Android Screen Size Compatibility: Bitmap?

Tags: android, css, bitmap, screen

What if I wanted to use a set bitmap size and with every device's size it gets it stretches to that appropriate screen size. Would this work in a practical environment like the google market for all if not most phones?

Can someone please clarify how this screen compability works.

My question is if it would work. Would all phones allow this bitmap/image to be stretched on all devices with no problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be stretched, yes.  Without problem depends on the image.  Some possible problems you'd see are pixelation (if magnified too much) or skew if the aspect ratio changes.  A 9 patch may fix that for a large range of sizes, but may or may not work well for your image.  The best thing to do is to try a single image, then move to a 9 patch if needed.  If that still doesn't work then you can include multiple images for different screen sizes.  Android has a built in system for changing resource files based on a variety of factors, including screen size.

Comment: Hi Gabe, this was the perfect answer I was looking for thank you so much for taking your time to respond to this! Please have a nice day :-)!!!